# Add text right side to to logo, and add sign up, and login sign up <li> to the right corner, and the other <li> to the centre

Tags: text, alignment

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74uQs.png)[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6YJe.png) [figma design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYFve.png)

how do I make the first image, of html & css, like my figma design, using html and css. please help

As you can see from what is resulted in the image, it has not worked out at all.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier to help if you could post your code :)
Putting
`display: flex; flex-direction: row`
on container elements should help